# what format will work for Mac and windows and handle an 8Gb to 20 Gb file?

Tags: windows-7, mac, virtualbox, format, fat32

I want to move my linux virtual machine's .vdi file from my Mac to my PC

It's a dropbox VM, and i'm pretty sure it will work on the PC, i just need a way to move it. I have a 16Gb USB and i've compressed the file down to 8 Gb in zip which seem to work on both Mac and PC. The USB is formatted to FAT 32 but it won't copy the file, i think because FAT32 can't handle files over 4Gb? what format do i need? and how do i reformat the USB on my Mac?

Answer (score 2):

three options - you can get readonly HTFS access on windows with [HFS explorer](http://catacombae.org/hfsx.html), NTFS access on OS X with macfuse and [ntfs 3g](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/ntfs3g.html), or simply make a [split zip archive](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zipsplit.1.html) - tho there might be an easier way for the last - i'm not a mac user.

Comment: You can get read/write HTFS in windows with macDrive, but it costs $$$. Or you could transfer over the network.

Comment: he only needs read-only. macdrive is an option if he's going to be doing this a lot

Comment: +1 macfuse and ntfs3g would be my pick. I've used them extensively.

Comment: how does macfuse compare to ntfs? pros and cons?

Comment: well, as i understand it, NTFS 3G runs on fuse - so you'd need to install macfuse as a prerequisite to install NTFS-3G.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than mucking about with file systems, just split the files up into manageable chunks, and join them on the other side.

You can use whichever archiving package works for you, to create split zip archives, or just go commando:

On your Mac, in a terminal, split the file like so:

```
split -b 3500m /path/to/the/large-file /output/filename
```

This will make 3500 MB chunks. Move them over, and reconstruct on Windows with a binary copy:

```
copy /b chunk1.file + chunk2.file + chunk3.file output.file
```

*Note: I am not a Mac user, but I am familiar with the commands as [shown here](http://www.machackpc.com/macosx/how-to-split-and-concat-a-large-file-using-terminal/)*

Answer (score 0):

NTFS-3G is an option. But nowadays the best solution is exFAT. It's specifically designed for flash drive, support files larger than 4GB and most important, both windows and mac can read/write from it without 3rd party driver