# What partition type for OS X and Windows 7 dual boot?

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning

AFAIK there is no partition type that OS X and Windows 7 can both read/write to, with a file size limit of more than ~4GB?

Anyone care to confirm or correct me?

Comment: Do you want to use a single partition for both systems?

Comment: @Daniel Beck - yep

Comment: possible duplicate of [what format will work for Mac and windows and handle an 8Gb to 20 Gb file?](http://superuser.com/questions/262084/what-format-will-work-for-mac-and-windows-and-handle-an-8gb-to-20-gb-file)

Comment: This will very likely *not* work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use FAT32 then yes, your maximum file size will be 4,294,967,295 bytes. However there are drivers available (for Windows and Mac OS X) which are capable of reading NTFS or HFS+. Unfortunately they mainly seem to be in the commercial area but here's a few I found:

- [NTFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) and [HFS+ for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/)
- [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/software/macdrive/)

Comment: The bootcamp drivers also enable you to write from your windows partition to your mac harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of OS X support the [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) (aka FAT64) volume format, which can handle ridiculously large files.  The Wikipedia entry claims support for it was added in OS X v10.6.5, while the [man page for mount_exfat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_exfat.8.html) implies it was added in v10.6.3; in either case, it's a pretty recent addition.